# Internal g suite email issues using a new tld

Tags: email, top-level-domains, google-workspace

I'm having issues with our G Suite email services since we switched from .com to .fun. I found articles from Google about new TLD's being ok for search but nothing about using that tld for an email address. The issues are quirky; filling out forms online and the email address being labelled invalid, etc. Is this a tld issue or how we set up; aka SPF, DKIM settings.

Comment: Did you set up SPF and DKIM?  If so, have you verified that they are correct using online or locally run tools?   If this is because of the TLD, it sounds like it has very little to do with Gsuite and more with assumptions about what makes a valid email address in form validation.

Comment: I agree. The issue is that common things like sending an email (not a campaign) or filling out online forms is hit or miss. I want to kick the tires on any set up issues with G Suite like dkim spf etc. but if non-traditional tld’s are prone to this type of issues then I don’t want to try and fix something that’s not fixable.